Is washing the lower part of the proximal nail fold obligatory in ghusl?
The proximal nail fold is the term for the fleshy part directly above the nail matrix or nail root. The lower part of the fold which is directly in contact with the matrix or root is supposed to be sealed but in my case it is not and water can seep in. Is washing this part during ghusl obligatory? Click here to look for the part in question

It is obligatory to ensure that every part of the body required in ablution is thoroughly washed, leaving no area dry.

The Prophet (ﷺ) once saw a man offering prayer with a small unwashed
spot on the back of his foot, about the size of a dirham. The Prophet
(ﷺ) instructed him to repeat both his ablution and prayer. (Sunan Abu
Dawood 175).

Therefore, it is essential to wash all parts completely, without leaving any area dry. There is no doubt that the nails are obligatory to clean, one can do this by washing his hands if he had woken up. Otherwise it is not obligatory to clean, if it is obligatory, then what is obligatory is obligatory upon him just like everybody else, he must wash his hands, including the nails.

Whoever wakes up from his sleep should wash his hands before putting
them in the water for ablution, because nobody knows where his hands
were during sleep." Sahih al-Bukhari 162


Then I'm doomed. I probably have hundreds of thousands of prayers to make up

I was referring to the lower part of the proximal nail fold. Not what's beneath the nail.

@Afiq No it's fine, if your ignorant then you won't be hold accountable. Besides that, there is no need to be worrying about such a small part, usually when you wash your hands it should reach the whole hands, so it'd be silly to be worrying.
